# If item_id has params - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Trying to check to see if two params are in an id field for an if statement in my rails app.

For example i want to state if both [params[:one], params[:two]] exist in column :item_id then continue, if not, don't include in results.

So in my example below it would only chose item_id one as both one and two params exist in the item_id.

Table

```
item_id | one  | two
   1    | 2300 | 2255
   1    | 2000 | 2304
   2    | 2300 | 2000
   3    | 2255 | 2222
```

View Form code

```
<%= form_tag vpc_search_path do %>

 <%= select_tag :one, options_from_collection_for_select(@variety, "variety_id", "variety_name", :selected => "2300"), include_blank: false %>
 <%= select_tag :two, options_from_collection_for_select(@variety, "variety_id", "variety_name", :selected => "2255"), include_blank: false %>
 <%= submit_tag "Compare" %>

<% end %>
```

Controller code

```
if Result.where(trial_id: [params[:one], params[:two]])
   @comparison = Result.where('variety_id' => [params[:one], params[:two]], 'year' => params[:year])
else
   redirect_to vpc_index_url, notice: "error."
end
```

Comment: I think it will be better if you explain your question with a proper example and exactly where do you want to do this check too ?

Comment: Apologies Magnum, I have added more information, hopefully i'm making sense :/

Answer (score 2):

probably you should move this check in model

```
if self.where(item_id: [params[:one] && params[:two]]).present? 

   then do this

else 

   do this

end
```

or probably if you can provide params hash structure I can improve my answer

Comment: Sorry I wrote down :item_id as a param, but its a column in my database.

Comment: Also you can use model callbacks too to do this check ,include this check in a specific method and use callback to call that method

Comment: just add .present? and you are good to go

 if Result.where(trial_id: [params[:one], params[:two]]).present?

Comment: above is looping back to vpc_index_url. If i change it to Result.where(one: [params[:one], params[:two]]).present? it works, but I want to group the trial_id's then for it to determine if both exist then continue on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand that right, but try this:

```
if SomeModel.where(item_id: [params[:one],params[:two]]).count == 2
  #params :one and :two are on the item_id column
else
  #one or both are not on the item_id column
end
```

please explain your problem better, it's hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

Further to the two answers which I upvoted already, you may want to consider this:

You'd use the `where` function to create the logic, but you need to consider how you're going to call this. Here's how I would do it:

---

**Custom Validator**

Might be a bit long-winded, but you may be able to create a [custom validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators), which you'll be able to call to determine if the `params` exist in the db:

```
class TableValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless self.where(item_id: [record.one && record.two]).present? 
      record.errors[:name] << 'Need a name starting with X please!'
    end
  end
end

class Table
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with TableValidator
end
```

I used Magnum's code for the logic & the [Rails guide for the custom validator](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

This probably won't work out of the box, but it's what I would look at

Comment: Hi @rich well I told him to move this check to model too but he prefers it in controller nice suggestion BTW........